# Expo useAuthRequest with devTools remote debugging throws error: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome

Tags: react-native, expo

This has to be a common issue, but I can't find anyone else that's had this problem...

Using Expo SDK 42, if I try to enable remote debugging in my project while using Expo's `AuthSession.useAuthRequest` in the exact same format as the docs
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#azure

```
// this is sample code from Expo, our implementation is basically identical
const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: 'your.app'
        }),
    },
    discovery
  );

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
        }}
    />
  );
```

The invocation of `useAuthRequest` throws this blocking error whenever opening remote debugging with Chrome

```
Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome.

 Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time.
```

Removing the call to `useAuthRequest` clears the error, so I'm pretty sure that's the problem. But if that's commented out, then I can't debug anything past auth on the app... any ideas on how to get around this?